# Sorting a zoo object by value

Tags: r, sorting, zoo

I have a zoo time series object. How do I sort it by value, while preserving the dates?

If this is my series:

```
2013-10-02 2013-10-03 2013-10-04 2013-10-07 2013-10-08 2013-10-09 
-0.02      0.00       0.00       0.04       0.00       0.02
```

The result should be:

```
2013-10-02 2013-10-03 2013-10-04 2013-10-08 2013-10-09 2013-10-07
-0.02      0          0          0          0.02       0.04
```

Ordinary `sort` sorts the zoo object by date (not value). zoo object (date, 1 value series) has dim NULL, so it's not possible to specify that I want to sort by the second column.

Comment: You can't sort a zoo object by anything other than the index. The ordered index is the fundamental design/purpose of the class. You're also confusing the index as a column of the object. It's an attribute, not a column. I suggest you read [the package vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/vignettes/zoo.pdf).

Answer (score 6):

Using your data in a data frame and converting to a `"zoo"` object:

```
df <- data.frame(Dates = as.Date(c("2013-10-02", "2013-10-03", "2013-10-04",
                                   "2013-10-07", "2013-10-08", "2013-10-09")),
                 Values = c(-0.02, 0.00, 0.00, 0.04, 0.00, 0.02))
library("zoo")
zdf <- zoo(df$Values, df$Dates)
```

Whilst @Joshua is correct, you can always convert back to a data frame representation and sort that, you just have to handle the preservation of the dates through the process. For example:

```
df2 <- as.data.frame(zdf)
df2 <- transform(df2, Dates = as.Date(rownames(df2)))
```

Now sort `df2`

```
df2[order(df2$zdf), ]

R> df2[order(df2$zdf), ]
             zdf      Dates
2013-10-02 -0.02 2013-10-02
2013-10-03  0.00 2013-10-03
2013-10-04  0.00 2013-10-04
2013-10-08  0.00 2013-10-08
2013-10-09  0.02 2013-10-09
2013-10-07  0.04 2013-10-07
```