# Reorder time series by data latest at top

Tags: r, time-series

I have a time series as

```
z <- structure(c(400L, 0L, 0L, 125L, 120L, 200L, 0L, 0L, 100L, 
0L), .Dim = c(5L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Quant1", "Quant2"
)), index = structure(c(15728, 15727, 15726, 15725, 15723), class = "Date"), 
class = "zoo")

coredata(z)[coredata(z) == 0] <- NA
```

So z becomes as

```
           Quant1 Quant2
2013-01-23    400    200
2013-01-22     NA     NA
2013-01-21     NA     NA
2013-01-20    125    100
2013-01-18    120     NA
```

Now I tried to use locf as

```
z <- na.locf(z, fromLast = T)

           Quant1 Quant2
2013-01-18    120     NA
2013-01-20    125    100
2013-01-21    125    100
2013-01-22    125    100
2013-01-23    400    200
```

Output is correct but reversed the sequence of date.

I want to calculate returns for this data using

```
rollapply(z,width=2,FUN=function(xx)if(is.finite(xx[2]/xx[1])) xx[2]/xx[1] else 0)-1
```

Output I get

```
               Quant1 Quant2
2013-01-18 0.04166667     -1
2013-01-20 0.00000000      0
2013-01-21 0.00000000      0
2013-01-22 2.20000000      1
```

Output I want

```
               Quant1 Quant2
2013-01-23 2.20000000      1
2013-01-22 0.00000000      0    
2013-01-21 0.00000000      0
2013-01-20 0.04166667     -1
```

Any suggestion?

**Update**
It would be great if I could reverse the order of series after using na.locf. That will solve my purpose, but not able to do it. I am new to R.

Comment: It seems like a dupe of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21101493/sorting-a-zoo-object-by-value), though not sure if there is any better way of solving this

Comment: Can we modify "rollapply(z,width=2,FUN=function(xx)if(is.finite(xx[2]/xx[1])) xx[2]/xx[1] else 0)-1" to get the desired result, as converting to and from might be performance hit

Comment: I don't know, I'm not familiar enough with `zoo`. Probably JU or GG could be more of help than me here.

Comment: `rev(z)` is your friend